# Swagger UI is Hangs with spring boot API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

We are using Spring boot 2.6 and Swagger UI for the rest APIs, initially, it works perfectly but when the controller and model object increase it's started hanging the swagger UI.

Comment: Are you using open api or Spring fox?

Comment: we are using open API.